# How to Set the tabindex on a Javascript Slider

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set the tabindex on the arrows associated with a slider [like this one](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_quotes_slideshow.asp), but the arrows get skipped when using tab to move from one element on the web page to the next. I tried this ...

```
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1).tabIndex = '3'">❮</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1).tabIndex = '4'">❯</a>
```

... without success. Maybe the tabIndex property requires that all elements are labeled w/ tabIndex for it to function? IDK.

Any thoughts / comments on how to implement this are welcome.

Comment: `<` should be replaced with `&lt;`.

Comment: Is there a risk using the ❮ and  ❯ ? Or, is it just bad form?

Comment: < signifies the start of a tag to the HTML parser and will technically make your HTML invalid (although it will probably render fine).

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1,3)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1,4)">❯</a>

function plusSlides(n,index) {
  showSlides(index += n);
}

function currentSlide(n,index) {
  showSlides(index = n);
}
```

send index in side function

Comment: `<` should be replaced with `&lt;`.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast reply, but I couldn't get this to work w/ the script.  It seemed to disable the slider's functionality; i.e., the arrows no longer activated the slide effect.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets). The slider's arrows are traversable w/ the keyboard's tab key when the tabindex is set as follows:

```
    <a class="prev" id="previd" tabindex="0" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
    <a class="next" id="nextid" tabindex="0" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
```